# GraphQL does not sort Turkish date field as expected

Tags: sorting, date, graphql

in Gatsby I have MarkDown posts. Frontmatter of each post has date field in Turkish format (dd MMMM yyyy). GraphQL query sorts posts only on dd portion not taking account of MMMM and yyyy portions. I expect DESC sort, Turkish Date format. any help please TIA

Comment: again - it's not graphql matter - follow gatsby docs ... change dates in md files into gatsby supported format or modify gatsby to support your date requirements

Comment: @xadm Thank you I'll try to modify Gatsby date format

Answer (score 1):

As @xadm said in his comment, you must adhere to the Gatsby date format:

Just change the date format in your md file as follows

```
date: "2019-05-04"
```

Read more on Gatsby docs [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/adding-markdown-pages/#frontmatter-for-metadata-in-markdown-files)